# Make the input restore the previous one when hitting up arrow instead of ^[[A in C

Tags: c

how can i make the program expect the `UP` arrow key and place the previous input value on the current one?

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]);

void parse(char* command){

    if(!strcmp(command,"exit")){
        exit(1);
    }

    main(0,NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char buffer[1024]; 

    printf("command > ");
    fgets(buffer , sizeof(buffer) , stdin);

    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;

    parse(buffer);

}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WfUR.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [readline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) library. Supporting for up arrow (and many other additional key bindings) does not exist with standard I/O, but it is readily available with [readline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html).

Also note that your program should loop over the input, instead of making recursive calls between main and parse.

```
   // This is prog.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

void parse(char* command){
    if(!strcmp(command,"exit")){
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char *buffer;

    while ((buffer = readline("command >")) != NULL) {
        add_history(buffer);
        parse(buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will have to build with `readline`:

```
cc prog.c -lreadline
```

For more information about `readline` please refer to this [`link`](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html)